# Error Installing Drupal 7 Date API on MAMP

Tags: drupal, error-handling, installation, localhost, mamp

When I install this Drupal 7 setup on localhost.

I receive this error:

```
    An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows. Path:      http://localhost:8888/drupal-testing/docroot-syn/install.php?profile=localvox&locale=en&id=1&op=do StatusText: OK ResponseText: Home | Drupal @import url("http://localhost:8888/drupal-testing/docroot-syn/modules/system/system.messages.css?0"); @import url("http://localhost:8888/drupal-testing/docroot-syn/modules/system/system.base.css?0"); @import url("http://localhost:8888/drupal-testing/docroot-syn/modules/system/system.theme.css?0"); @import url("http://localhost:8888/drupal-testing/docroot-syn/modules/system/system.menus.css?0"); @import url("http://localhost:8888/drupal-testing/docroot-syn/modules/comment/comment.css?0"); @import url("http://localhost:8888/drupal-testing/docroot-syn/sites/all/modules/contrib/date/date_api/date.css?0"); @import url("http://localhost:8888/drupal-testing/docroot-syn/sites/all/modules/contrib/date/date_popup/themes/datepicker.1.7.css?0"); @import url("http://localhost:8888/drupal-testing/docroot-syn/modules/field/theme/field.css?0"); @import url("http://localhost:8888/drupal-testing/docroot-syn/modules/node/node.css?0"); @import url("http://localhost:8888/drupal-testing/docroot-syn/modules/user/user.css?0"); @import url("http://localhost:8888/drupal-testing/docroot-syn/sites/all/modules/contrib/views/css/views.css?0"); @import url("http://localhost:8888/drupal-testing/docroot-syn/modules/system/system.admin.css?0"); @import url("http://localhost:8888/drupal-testing/docroot-syn/modules/system/system.maintenance.css?0"); @import url("http://localhost:8888/drupal-testing/docroot-syn/sites/all/modules/contrib/ctools/css/ctools.css?0"); @import url("http://localhost:8888/drupal-testing/docroot-syn/themes/seven/reset.css?0"); @import url("http://localhost:8888/drupal-testing/docroot-syn/themes/seven/style.css?0"); Home Installation tasksChoose profile(done)Choose language(done)Verify requirements(done)Set up database(done)Install profile(active)Configure siteFinished Warning message The Date API requires that you set up the site timezone and first day of week settings and the date format settings to function correctly. Attempt to create a field of unknown type searchrank.
```

What is the problem?

I tried increasing php.ini; it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Error does not tell me much but it is either a limitation of your local host getting on way or some AJAX related module causing some mix ups.
Try exporting you Drupal to some server or some other local host simulators. If the error persists try updating modules. Update ctools module because is is very important jet is was a bit messy lately. 
Really this an issue and you could go to the module`s issue page and post about it there.